# Swift - Sort NSDictionary to Array by NSDate

Tags: swift

How can I sort a Dictionary of type

```
 var daysChart: Dictionary<NSDate, [Double]>
```

?

I've tried but I get an error `Cannot find overload for sorted that accepts argument type '(Dictionary, (_, _) -> _)'

```
 var daysChartArray = sorted(daysChart) {$0.0 < $1.0}
```

Comment: so I can not go for example by $0.0 < $1.0 ?

Comment: I've read "Meaning that we can use sorted() with String and Dictionary instances, because they inherit the SequenceType protocol through adoption of CollectionType."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the sorted won't return new dictionary, but an array of (k, v) tuples. If this is what you want, you can modify your compare to something like:

```
{$0.0.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate < $1.0.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate}
```

I don't have Swift 1.2 around, but in Swift 2, it would look like this:

```
let a = daysChart.sort { (lhs, rhs) -> Bool in
    return lhs.0.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate < rhs.0.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
}
```

But again, it returns an array...

Comment: Yeah I was aware of the fact It would return an array, but wasn't sure why the error was being shown. So I see NSDates can't be normally be compared, I guess we could use the compare function to do that, thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my type to

```
Dictionary<String, [Double]>
```

and now the sorted function works